# Вопрос по отрисовке layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Нужно в прилоге реализовать 2 лэйаута, что бы они были разделены косой чертой, как на примере. Как это можно сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: эти синяя и белая области должны реагировать на клик соответственно (клик по синей части - одно действие, по белой - другое)?

Comment: Да, нужно 2 области, которые по-разному будут реагировать на нажатия

Answer (score -1):

Есть понятие как Fragment Activity, [вот документация на русском](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), вроде понятно написано. А черту можно будет дорисовать руками, например через Canvas